# Serverless: Custom Lambda Function name

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless framework for my aws lambda function.
Suppose my function name is '**service1**' ‘**function1**’ in my serverless.yml file. When i deploy it, my lambda function name becomes: ‘**service1-dev-function1**’. I understand **dev** is because default stage is dev, but i dont want any stage related name in my lambda function. I just want my function to be ‘**function1**’. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reason for that. If you ever wanted to deploy that function into production you can add `--stage prod` which will change the name of the function to match the stage. If you handled naming yourself, you could end up with a conflict later where the deployment will tell you it cannot complete because that Lambda function with the name `function1` already exists.

After saying all that, you can control the name of the function in AWS explicitly as well. Just add a `name` parameter to your function definition the same way you do `handle`. You can see this on this serverless.yml reference page which is usually my first port of call for these kinds of questions I usually have as well as that reference contains pretty much every configuration option available to you:

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/#serverlessyml-reference/

Comment: I missed the service part. Generally it is 'servicename-stage-functionName'. I just want to have 'functionname-stage'. I wans't aware of the name properyty in function. Thank the help

Comment: Its again done this way to prevent collisions. You may have another service with the same function name on the same stage.